# table elements not detecting :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

so I have a small problem with my code. In my `<aside>` element, I have a table. I have added titles to each of the images in the table, however they simply aren't displaying upon mousing over the image. I also have something in my css, that changes the colour of the table row and text, upon hovering over it. This also is not working. I have pasted the relevant code below, any help is appreciated. :D

**HTML**
`

```
<aside class="second">
    <center><u>Popular Champions</u></center>
        <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Champion</th>
    <th>Playrate (%)</th>
    <th>Lane</th>
    <th>Difficulty</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="Thresh.png"  title="Thresh" alt="Thresh"/></td>
    <td>42.75%</td>
    <td>Support</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="LeeSin.png"  title="Lee Sin" alt="Lee Sin"/></td>
    <td>38.14%</td>
    <td>Jungle</td>
    <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="Caitlyn.png"  title="Caitlyn" alt="Caitlyn"/></td>
    <td>34.79%</td>
    <td>ADC</td>
    <td>1/5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="Ezreal.png"  title="Ezreal" alt="Ezreal"/></td>
    <td>25.14%</td>
    <td>ADC</td>
    <td>1/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Blitzcrank.png"  title="Blitzcrank" alt="Blitzcrank"/></td>
    <td>22.82%</td>
    <td>Support</td>
    <td>3/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Elise.png"  title="Elise" alt="Elise"/></td>
    <td>22.62%</td>
    <td>Jungle</td>
    <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Ahri.png"  title="Ahri" alt="Ahri"/></td>
    <td>17.15%</td>
    <td>Middle</td>
    <td>5/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Orianna.png"  title="Orianna" alt="Orianna"/></td>
    <td>16.50%</td>
    <td>Middle</td>
    <td>3/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Fiora.png"  title="Fiora" alt="Fiora"/></td>
    <td>16.18%</td>
    <td>Top</td>
    <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Graves.png"  title="Graves" alt="Graves"/></td>
    <td>15.98%</td>
    <td>Jungle</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</aside>
```

`

**CSS**

`

```
aside tr:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

`

**EDIT**
Turns out Hyperlinks positioned above (in a separate  element are also not registering any form of mouse input (unclickable links) I have pasted my entire code below:

**HTML**
`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LoL Guide: Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/" target="_blank">
            <img src="Logo.png">
            </a>
            <h1>League Of Legends Beginner's Guide</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li><a href="page2.html">Champions</a></li>
                <li><a href="page3.html">Gameplay</a></li>        
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <aside class="New">
        <center> <u>Useful Links</u> </center>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/" target="_blank">Official League of Legends website.</a> </li> 
        <li><a href="http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki" target="_blank">Official League of Legends Wiki</a> </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/" target="_blank">Official League of Legends Reddit</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <aside class="second">
    <center><u>Popular Champions</u></center>
        <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Champion</th>
    <th>Playrate (%)</th>
    <th>Lane</th>
    <th>Difficulty</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="Thresh.png"  title="Thresh" alt="Thresh"/></td>
    <td>42.75%</td>
    <td>Support</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="LeeSin.png"  title="Lee Sin" alt="Lee Sin"/></td>
    <td>38.14%</td>
    <td>Jungle</td>
    <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="Caitlyn.png"  title="Caitlyn" alt="Caitlyn"/></td>
    <td>34.79%</td>
    <td>ADC</td>
    <td>1/5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="Ezreal.png"  title="Ezreal" alt="Ezreal"/></td>
    <td>25.14%</td>
    <td>ADC</td>
    <td>1/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Blitzcrank.png"  title="Blitzcrank" alt="Blitzcrank"/></td>
    <td>22.82%</td>
    <td>Support</td>
    <td>3/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Elise.png"  title="Elise" alt="Elise"/></td>
    <td>22.62%</td>
    <td>Jungle</td>
    <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Ahri.png"  title="Ahri" alt="Ahri"/></td>
    <td>17.15%</td>
    <td>Middle</td>
    <td>5/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Orianna.png"  title="Orianna" alt="Orianna"/></td>
    <td>16.50%</td>
    <td>Middle</td>
    <td>3/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Fiora.png"  title="Fiora" alt="Fiora"/></td>
    <td>16.18%</td>
    <td>Top</td>
    <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="Graves.png"  title="Graves" alt="Graves"/></td>
    <td>15.98%</td>
    <td>Jungle</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</aside>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">To become a good League of Legends player, there is a great learning curve. During this curve, the player is expected to master each of the key features of the game, in order to dominate their opposition. During the course of this guide, My aim will be to both educate you and to attempt to provide you with an understanding of the many key gameplay aspects that the game posseses.
        <hr>
        <center><u>An Ever Changing Meta</u></center>
        Riot Games (League of Legend's developers) frequently update the game, sometimes as often as every two weeks. This brings new content constantly, with almost constant changes to various champions.
        <br>
        <center><img src="Malhazar.jpg" alt="Malhazar" height="300" width="630" border="5" title="Malhazar"></center>
        Levels 1 to 30 are fairly straight forward, allowing the player to become experienced at the game. After the player reaches level 30, they can play ranked. Ranked is a much harder version of the game, where people will be trying their hardest, in order to try and attain a high rank. The ranks are shown below.

        <div class="slider">
            <figure>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Bronze</p>
            <img src="bronze.png" alt="Bronze">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Silver</p>
            <img src="silver.png" alt="Silver">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Gold</p>
            <img src="gold.jpg" alt="Gold">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Platinum</p>
            <img src="platinum.jpg" alt="Platinum">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Diamond</p>
            <img src="diamond.png" alt="Diamond">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <p>Challenger</p>
            <img src="challenger.jpg">
            </div>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <br>
        Using an account that is already level 30, when first starting the game is generally discouraged. This is because the game will match you against <u>Any</u> level 30 players. This means anything from Bronze players, through to Diamond. With over 100 champions, its safe to say that with the broad range of champions available, any one of them can be effective when played right. This makes it a simple case of finding your main.
        <hr>
        <center><u>Free Rotation</u></center>
        Every week, there are 10 champions on free rotation. During this time, anyone can pick them and play as them. The 10 champions usually range in both champion type and popularity. As the 10 champions change every week, this gives users a chance to play a wide range of champions, and may influence their decision as to whether they want to purchase it.
        <br>
        <center><img src="freerotation.jpg" alt="Malhazar" height="300" width="630" border="5" title="Current Free rotation"></center>
        <u>This Week's free rotation is as follows:</u>
        <ol>
           <li> Ashe. -<i>The Frost Archer.</i> </li>
            <li> Vel'Koz. -<i>The Eye Of The Void.</i></li>
            <li> Yorick. -<i>The shepherd Of Souls.</i> </li>
            <li> Azir. -<i>The Emperor Of The Sands.</i></li>
            <li> Rammus. -<i>The Armordillo.</i></li>
            <li> Caitlyn. -<i>The Sheriff Of Piltover.</i></li>
            <li> Fiddlesticks. -<i>The Harbinger Of Doom.</i></li>
            <li> Ekko. -<i>The Boy Who Shattered Time.</i> </li>
            <li> Karma. -<i>The Enlightened One.</i> </li>
            <li> Kennen. -<i>The Heart Of The Tempest.</i></li>
        </ol>

    </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="Footer">
    <table>
        <th>Contact Us</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Champions</th>
        <th>Gameplay</th>

    </table>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

`

**CSS**
`

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("backgroundimage.png");
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
header {
     background: linear-gradient(#2e2e30, #cbcbd6);
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 15px 0 10px;
}
header h1{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
nav img {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -13px;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: **;
    display: table;
}

.col {
    float: left;
    background: #333;
    width: 60%;
    margin: .5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5%;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -16px;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    background: #333;
    width: 30%;
    margin: .5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5%;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
}
center u {
    font-size: 25px;
}

aside a { 
color: white;
}

.slider .slide p {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top 10px;
    right: -130px;


}

.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
}

.slider figure div {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
.slider figure img{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.slider figure{
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 20px;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite;

}

@keyframes slidy{
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    10% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    12%{
        left: -100%;
    }

    22% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    24% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    34% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    36% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    46% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    48% {
        left: -400%;
    }

    58% {
        left: -400%;
    }

    60% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    70% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    72% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    82% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    84% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    94% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    96% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        left: 0%;
    }

}

.slider {
    position:;
    right: -250px;
    top: -10px;
    height: 370px;
    float: left;
}

.second {
    position: relative;
    left: 381.5px;
    top: 160px;
}

.row {
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px
}

aside table{
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
}

aside table img{
    display:block;
}

footer {
    float: left;
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: .5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5%;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 350px;
}

aside tr:hover  {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

your `.row` DIV has `position: absolute` and is covering the first aside element completely, that's why the mouse-pointer doesn't change and no clicks can get through to the links. Either change that àbsolute` or move the aside further to the right to fix that.

Comment: I've since noticed that the hyperlinks also in the first <aside> box aren't working also, leading me to believe it is the entire <aside> not registering any mouse input. Any thoughts on a fix for that one? Thanks for the help so far, nevertheless.

Comment: I don't know which links you are talking about, but the hover *IS* working, as you can see in my snippet (and the titles display is working too in there).

Comment: I updated my question with my entire script. The links in question are in the <aside> section. Its as if both the <aside> sections aren't registering that there is a mouse there :/

Comment: NOTE MY CHANGED ANSWER